# Firebase rules & security

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database like this:

[image]

The first key is the userId, has to be connected, and the next keys only him can read and write. How I can manage the rules to be safe and no one can't see the key of each other ? I begin with that but I don't think is enough

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: So your top node, `UWgfq...` in this case, is the user ID?

Comment: Yeah it's the user Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the user ID as a key you can use it in your rules to make sure users can only read/write to their own nodes like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
  }
}
```

For more information you can take a look at the firebase docs about [User Based Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) and [Securing Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data). For a more extencive answer about linking users to their data you can take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30912711/4916627).