# creating a new user entry in firebase database, everytime a user signs up in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on a quiz app, where a user signs up with email and pw via firebase.

After the signup he shall pass a nickname which will be used in for a highscore.

So basically I want the app to add a these kind of user information, everytime a user signs up as shown in the attached picture.

[image]

In order to achieve this I used this code:

```
public class createNickname extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "createNickname";

    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private EditText NicknameInput;
    private Button NicknameReg;
    private String Nickname, UserId;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String EmailEntry;
    private DatabaseReference myref = mFirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_nickname);

        NicknameInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNickname);
        NicknameReg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btsetNickname);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        myref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot ) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "value is: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError ) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });

        NicknameReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View view ) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Attempting to add object to database.");
                String newNick = NicknameInput.getText().toString();
                if (!newNick.equals("")) {
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    UserId = user.getUid();
                    EmailEntry = user.getEmail();
                    myref.child("userlist").push().setValue(UserId);
                    myref.child("userlist").child(UserId).push().setValue(EmailEntry);
                    myref.child("userlist").child(UserId).push().setValue(0);

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    }
 }
```

So the question is now, what did I do wrong?
A user is created in the authentication window in firebase, but the database is just not updated.

Did I target the database correctly? How do u decided which database you want to target?

These are my firebase security rules: 
{ 
 "rules": { 
   ".read": false, 
   ".write": false 
 } 
}

Regarding the database nothing is happening if i get it right.

I get no error message what so ever.

Comment: What exactly is happening? What are your expectations and the actual results? Any errors? (In case of permission denied errors you should also post your security rules) I can probably help you but i need a bit more info.

Comment: These are my firebase security rules:

{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}


Regarding the database nothing is happening if i get it right. Is there something that you need as well?

Ahh end I get now error message what so ever

Comment: Can you include that information in your question? You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50511594/edit) button below your question.

Comment: done, is there anything else to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would advice to [add a completion callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) to your code so you know when and if your writes to Firebase have failed/succeeded.

In your case you would get a permission denied error because your security rules are set to false -> nobody has permission to read/write to your database. Instead you could give each user permission to write to their own data like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "userlist": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(See [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-variable) for more information)

For the above to work you will also have to change your code you are using to write to the database. Currently you are using `push()`. This [generates a random id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) and you don't need (want) that here. Instead you can use [setValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write):

<strike>myref.child("userlist").push().setValue(UserId);</strike>

```
myref.child("userlist").child(UserId).child("email").setValue(EmailEntry);
myref.child("userlist").child(UserId).child("highscore").setValue(0);
```

You can also look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30912711/4916627) for a bit more information about this subject.