# Creating a user with additional data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

Dear Firebase and Angular gurus. I managed to create a user through `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, but when I register a user, he still enters data about himself, and not just `email` and `password`. How can I do this? Create a document with the user id and write all the information there, or can Firebase do it smartly?

Comment: I suppose you can store other (not authentication related) data to firestore database (separated from authentication data).
I think your problem is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910704/how-do-i-link-each-user-to-their-data-in-firebase

Comment: "Create a document with the user id" is the way to go. Credentials storage is separated from your document DB and is not "extensible".